# Receive a video stream in the client html5 player

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, video, html5-video

I have an S3 bucket, I'm <s>downloading</s> uploading the file to the server, and I'm trying to send that video (`.mp4`) file to the client from the server, as far as I'm aware the server is working correctly, it is indeed sending a stream to the client.

**Problem:**
The frontend (NextJS, showing only an HTML5 video player) is not doing anything, I set the `src` tag to the location on the API to serve up the correct video, but it'll do a slight loading screen and then nothing. I need a set of fresh eyes to look at this.

**(1)** Here is the server controller:

```
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import fs from 'fs';
import errorHandler from '../../middleware/error.js';
import Video from '../../models/videoModel.js';
import getObjectFromBucketV2 from '../Wasabi/getObjectFromBucketV2.js';
import convertBufferToStream from '../../utils/convertBufferToStream.js';
import path from 'path';

/**
 * @description this function handles the streaming of a VOD record, it will find the record in the database, download the video from the cloud storage provider,
 *              and then brake the video into chunks and stream it to the client.
 * @param {Object} req - The request object
 * @param {Object} res - The response object
 * @route GET /api/v1/videos/stream/:videoId
 * @returns {Object} - Returns a response object
 *
 * @author Austin Howard
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 1.0
 *
 */
export default expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(
      `Video stream request received for videoId: ${req.params.videoId}`
    );
    // make sure videoId is a mongoose ObjectId
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.videoId)) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Invalid videoId',
      });
    }
    // find the video record in the database
    const video = await Video.findById(req.params.videoId).populate(
      'user',
      '_id fullName username'
    );
    // console.log(video);
    // if the video record is not found, return a 404 error
    if (!video) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Video not found',
      });
    }
    // this can only work for files that have a status of 'finished' as they are the only files that have been uploaded to the cloud storage provider
    if (video.status !== 'finished') {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Video is not ready to stream',
      });
    }
    // check if the range header is present in the request
    const range = req.headers.range;
    console.log(`Range header: ${range}`);
    // console.log(req.headers);
    // if the range header is not present, return a 400 error
    if (!range) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Range header not found',
      });
    }
    // get the start and end positions of the video file
    // create a read stream of the video file
    const videoStreamData = await getObjectFromBucketV2(
      video.user,
      video.wasabiKey,
      'videos'
    );
    const videoPath = path.join(
      path.resolve(`./public/videos/${video.videoTitle}.mp4`)
    );
    // write the video file from the videoStreamData to the file system
    await fs.writeFileSync(
      videoPath,
      Buffer.from(videoStreamData.data.Body, 'binary')
    );
    // get the stats of the video file
    const videoStats = await fs.statSync(videoPath);
    // get the size of the video file
    const videoSize = videoStats.size;

    const positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
    // set the chunk size equal to 1mb
    const chunkSize = 10 ** 6;
    // get the start position of the video file
    const start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
    // get the end position of the video file
    const end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, videoSize - 1);
    // console.log(typeof video.compressedSize);
    // set the content type of the response
    res.set({
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${video.compressedSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunkSize,
      'Content-Type': "application/x-mpegURL",
    });
    // set the status code of the response
    // *206 means partial content, telling the client that the response is only part of the video file
    // *and that the client should request the rest of the video file
    res.status(206);
    // create a read stream of the video file
    const videoStream = await fs.createReadStream(videoPath, {
      start,
      end,
      // return an encoding of 'binary' so that the video file can be streamed to the client
      encoding: 'binary',
      // return the data as a buffer
      highWaterMark: chunkSize,

    });
    // console.log(videoStream);
    // send the stream to the client
    videoStream.pipe(res, { end: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    errorHandler(error, req, res);
  }
});
```

**(2)** Here is the frontend code that serves up the video player:

```
import React from 'react';
import Page from '../../layouts/page/Page.layout';
import PrivateRoute from '../../components/PrivateRoute';
import VideoJS from '../../components/videoPlayer/component/VideoJS.component';
import axios from '../../utils/axios';

const Test = (urlparams) => {
  return (
    <Page meta={{ title: 'Test' }} view="admin-Test">
      <PrivateRoute permissions={['isAdmin']}>
        <video
          id="Video"
          controls
        >
          <source
            src="http://localhost:5000/api/v1/video/stream/639fa392e21d94e4c22369a9"
            headers={{ Range: 'bytes=0-100' }}
            type="application/x-mpegURL"
            preload="none"
            
          />
        </video>
      </PrivateRoute>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Some notes that might be helpful, the video file stored in my S3 bucket is an **MP4**, and initially I set the `type` on the video to `type=video/mp4` but that also didn't give the expected result.

Comment: I don't use ReactJS or NodeJS so maybe someone will advise you soon. In the meantime...  **(1)** Let me know what this does: `headers={{ Range: 'bytes=0-100' }}`... Are you only loading the first 100 bytes of the MP4? If yes, what happens if you instead try getting first 5 MB (or nearest) then does a picture show on the player? **(2)** Using **Axios**?? Make sure you're getting bytes (not text) **(3)** Why not just use the path of S3 URL as your video source? If try to do chunked streaming then best to: First convert your MP4 into fragmented-MP4 (also called ISOBMFF in some video converters).

Comment: **PS:** A fragmented (or chunked) MP4 means you'll get a main/master header (around 800 bytes) followed by chunks that each have their own chunk header. To avoid tripping the MPEG decoder, you send main header first then afterwards you can safely slice at the start of a chunk's header. Each chunk-header tells you the chunk's size/length of bytes so you can calculate a slice position by reading and adding up the sizes. It all depends if whether you make your fragmented MP4 as one long file of (internal) chunks or else you save each chunk as a separate file (eg: a bunch of **.m4s** files)

Comment: @VC.One the `headers={{ Range: 'bytes=0-100'}}` was just to see if i was receiiving a `range` header on the server, 2. in this example im not using `axios` though it is defined because i was trying different things, in this case i made an axios request to the server just to see what was being returned, 3. i dont want to use the direct link to the s3 bucket, because im trying to find ways to protect the video file itself, similar to how if you inspect a youtube video element you dont get the direct link to were the video is hosted, otherwise, people may download protected content.

Comment: @VC.One i want to clarify though, that a direct link to the s3 does indeed work though, its how im currently doing it, but i want to ensure the security of the video as well, so thats why im trying to implement this.

Comment: In the Server Controller, replace the **content-type** `"application/x-mpegURL"` with `"application/octet-stream"` (since the server is giving a bytes stream) and then in your `<video>` tag it should have `type="video/mp4"` (since the bytes represent MP4 data). That will get you ready to display a frame. Now all that matters is that the incoming stream is in a correct format. Test a [small MP4 file](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4) where you read the whole file and see if it plays.

Comment: PS: If playback fails on the small MP4, then save a copy of the received bytes and share for analysis (maybe use a Hex editor to show us by pasting here the first 50 bytes).

Comment: @VC.One i figured out what the issue was, it had to do with the `content-range` headers i set in the response, `video.compressedSize` is an undefined value (though it IS defined, but because i have mongo set to strict, and its not defined on my model. it comes back as undefined). once i changed this out for `videoSize` that i defined earlier, the stream started working!

Comment: OK. Glad it's solved now. PS: So do you have a fragmented or a just normal MP4?

Comment: @VC.One it was a full mp4 video, i watched several (short) videos in order to see that i was getting the correct data back, and it seems to be working. Now all i have to do is modify the file on the server, to not store it in the `public/videos` space, and instead, send it directly to the client without stashing it on the file system if i can do that then ill have acheived my goals for this project